# Adding two variables to Ajax name not workign

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using Ajax to create numerous carts which are named 'Bay'. I want to be able to increment the number each time the call is made for example, 'Bay 1', 'Bay 2', 'Bay 3' etc.

So far i have this but it's returning NaN?

```
// add new cart ...
     var limit = 1;
     var bayname = "Bay";

    case 'insert':
            this.ajax({
                'name': bayname + limit,
                'command': command
            }, function(data){
                BMCWcMs.reload();
                limit = limit + 1;
            });

        break;
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Try putting ".toString()" on limit before appending.  Otherwise, please provide a more complete example of the issue.

Comment: What line is returning NaN?

Comment: `bayname + limit.toString()`. otherwise, because limit is a number, it thinks you want to use + as a mathemtical operator rather than a string concatenator.